# Where can I find the C specification for combining strings?

Tags: c, string, specifications

When I read the source code of Xtables, I found something like this.

```
pr_info("SRC=" NIP6_FMR "DST=" NIP6_FMR "\n",
        NIP6(iph->saddr), NIP6(iph->daddr));
```

I wondered why the strings are dealt as a combined string and whether the effect is caused by the `pr_info` macro, or is part of the C specification. So, I wrote this code and find out that it is the defined behaviour in the C specification.

```
int main(void) {
    char a[] = "aaa" "bb";
    printf("%s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Where is the specification is defined? I do not know how to search about the specification and what word to use to express the behaviour.

Comment: You can find it [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2). It's the online version of N1570, the last draft of C11 prior to publication of the ISO standard. The standard itself needs to be bought, but the draft is very close to it.

Comment: If you look earlier in your code, you will probably find `#define NIP6_FMR "%p"` (or something similar) that defines what *format specifier* will replace the `NIP6_FMR` constant to complete the *format string*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [**6.4.5p8**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p8) an example:-

> This pair of adjacent character string literals
>
> `"\x12" "3"` produces a **single character string literal containing the two characters whose values are `'\x12'` and `'3'`**, because
>   escape sequences are converted into single members of the execution
>   character set just prior to adjacent string literal concatenation.

And also it is stated here in [**6.4.5p5**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p5)

> In translation phase 6, the multibyte character sequences specified by
>   any sequence of adjacent character and identically-prefixed string
>   literal tokens are **concatenated into a single multibyte character
>   sequence**.

Also, in section [**5.1.1.2**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) "Translation phases"

> 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

*emphasis mine*